# C: Working with strcmp

Tags: c, string, fgets, strcmp

As a beginner I've been playing around with some of the functions of the library `string.h` and have some issues regarding the function `strcmp`.

I wrote the program comparing two string. If they are equal it returns `YES` and `NO` otherwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char a[100];
    char b[15] = "hello";

    fgets(a, 100, stdin);

    int compare;

    compare = strcmp(a, b);

    if(compare == 0) {

        printf("YES");
    }
    else {

        printf("NO");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After running it even when I input from the keyboard a `hello` I get a `NO`. When I add the line `printf("%d", compare)` it turns out that for any input I get a `1`, that is, the stopping character in `a` is greater than the one in `b`.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The problem is not with `strcmp` but with what [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) does and how it works.

Comment: It works with gcc on tio. You can [try it here](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#bY@xDoMgEIZ3nuJCF0xMg0Mna7eu7dCpMQ6IqCSABnFqfHYLarRDb@DCf9/d/TefpOFqrARcB1fJ7tze0K9kpWmChqRxoJk0JIIPQuCDt8wCyxNKi/QQyjy5FJABboVSHU5Xtm6EGwiLwdMxhE0m2kphMO90z6zYlO3nh/j9XPehr9zxmuz1DOjuJkTv3bqa4Pf9haPV07S8Qg3iH/h4HtySrHCjNUBTNM3zcsEX).

Comment: @izlin: That would mean tio does not provide a compliant standard library.

Comment: @Olaf - Or that the "input" field in the online compiler doesn't append a newline to the input :)

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yes, that would also be a reason. But that would also mean it differs from a compliant environment. (That's one of the reasons I don't like online compilers).

Comment: @Olaf - You can get a compliant environment to behave the same by inputting EOF instead of a newline, can you not? I think online compilers just exemplify that there is still much to consider even when using the stdio facilities. The input stream abstraction isn't perfectly abstract.

Comment: @StoryTeller: If I hit the return-key in an input field, I expect it to be handled as expected. Of course, I assume izlin did not compare apples with oranges. Maybe I assumed too much.

Comment: @Olaf - izlin did. Hitting return inserts a newline (just tested).

Comment: @StoryTeller: Ok, I retract my comment about that particular platform then. Want an orange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgets` appends the new line character corresponding to the Enter key if there is enough space in the source array.

You should remove the character before comparing the string with another string the following way

```
a[strcspn( a, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char a[100];
    char b[15] = "hello";

    fgets(a, 100, stdin);

    a[strcspn( a, "\n" )] = '\0';

    int compare;

    compare = strcmp(a, b);

    if(compare == 0) {

        printf("YES");
    }
    else {

        printf("NO");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`fgets(a, 100, stdin);` stores the newline you input into the buffer as well. As such `a` contains `"hello\n"`. That extra character offsets the comparison.

You can either try to remove the newline by some means<sup>1</sup>, or compare with [`strncmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) instead.

---

1. For instance:

   ```
   char *newline = strchr(a, '\n');
   if (newline)
     *newline = '\0';
   ```

Answer (score 4):

It's not a mistake in scanning as such, but the problem is, [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) scans and stores the trailing newline into the supplied buffer. You need to get rid of that in case you're comparing the buffer with a string literal which does not contain the terminating newline as part of it.

For stripping the trailing newline, you can use something like

```
size_t len = strlen(a);
if (len > 0 && a[len-1] == '\n') {
    a[--len] = '\0';
}
```

[*See this answer for more reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27729970/2173917)

Without striping out the newline, `strcmp()` will not announce the comparison as success.

Otherwise, you can use [`strncmp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp) and supply the size of the string literal to keep the comparison limited to the *valid* input.

Comment: `strncmp()` is no good unless you also check the length of the input string to make sure it is as short as the literal string otherwise (for example) `hello` and `hello goodbye` would compare equal.

Comment: @JeremyP Yes, of course, that is why I mentioned _"limited to the valid input"_